# How to get External Storage Directory path in Android 10+

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to Read files from External Storage,
I developing Android App for Android 10+

I use this code to targetpath in android lower 9 version, but while using this code in Android 10 it's not working

```
String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera";
        System.out.println("FilePath1" + targetPath);


//---->Output Filepath1

I/System.out: FilePath1/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera
```

I tried this code for Android 10 but I getting Output something different:

```
File fileff = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera");
        System.out.println("FilePath2" + fileff);


//---->Output Filepath2

I/System.out: FilePath2/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.learning.mylearning/files/DCIM/Camera
```

please help me, how should I get Filepath1 in Android 10?

Thanks in Advance =)

Comment: You can't directly access files this way anymore in Android 10. See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage

Comment: You will get the same path if you use the same code.

Comment: Then please any solution, if possible little bit code, By Reading Documentation i getting more confusion, please help

Comment: `how should I get Filepath1 in Android 10?` That i already told you: use the same code.

Comment: What type of files are you trying to read?

Comment: Obviously the reason for his question is that getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated. Can his first filepath given be accessed another way?